# MS Access 2010 Macro Builder: SetProperty of control on parent form

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am trying to use the SetProperty macro (embedded on a subform click event) to enable a command button on it's parent form. The error being displayed is that it can't find the control or it's name is misspelled. (Error no. 32004). I have tested this myself several times for example by referencing a control within the same form and it works fine. The problem seems to arise when another form is referenced before the control.

Details of objects: 
Parent Form Name: frmSelectStaff 
Subform control Name: sfrmSelectStaff 
Subform name: sfrmSelectStaff 
Event: sfrmSelectStaff:Click 
Action Required: Enable command button (cmdAbsences) on parent form.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add relevant parts of the code you're working on?

Comment: I'm trying to use the macro builder with the following code.

<b>IF</b> [fldID] Is Not Null <b>Then</b>
<b>SetProperty</b>
ControlName: Forms!frmSelectStaff!cmdAbsences
Property: Enabled
Value: True
<b>End If</b>

Comment: Please ignore the <b> tags as I was trying to make some parts bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to reference the parent form from a subform using VBA:

```
Private Sub cmdToggle_Click()
    If Me.Parent!Command6.Enabled = False Then
        Me.Parent!Command6.Enabled = True
    Else
        Me.Parent!Command6.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply but I was trying to use macro builder as much as possible. Do you think it would be best with VBA or does it make a difference. Thanks.

Comment: In my case, I would use VBA. Some of the applications I have worked on have required extensive use of VBA, and since I am looking at the code, it was easier to just look at the VBA code than it was to go elsewhere to find the macro.  Although I am now retired, I also learned that 'getting it to work soon' was sometimes the most important... If I was stumped, I developed a solution, made a note, then when peace returned, I would go back to figure out what happened. I tried many combinations to use a macro for this -- even the macro builder creates the reference -- but still get the error.